# view pager for scrolling the activity in android

Tags: android

I am working on a multi page app, in which I need to put a page view, I am new with android so I don't know more about it , I researched a lot and found some relevant solution but that's not work for me.

```
 mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(mViewPager);

    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Simple"),
            CountingFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("List"),
            FragmentPagerSupport.ArrayListFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Cursor"),
            CursorFragment.class, null);
```

but still I did not get the expected result.

Comment: What error or problems are you facing ?

Comment: I was geting the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);        
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyOnPageChangeListener());

        LayoutInflater mLi = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view1 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.whats1, null);
        View view2 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.whats2, null);
        View view3 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.whats3, null);
        View view4 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.whats4, null);
        View view5 = mLi.inflate(R.layout.whats5, null);

        final ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
        views.add(view1);
        views.add(view2);
        views.add(view3);
        views.add(view4);
        views.add(view5);

        PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
                return arg0.equals(arg1);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return views.size();
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView(views.get(position));
            }



            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                container.addView(views.get(position));
                return views.get(position);
            }
        };

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

please notice that the 4 override method inside PagerAdapter is necessary for accomplishing ViewPager.